# Laravel Eloquent concat and groupBy() AND return one title of each group

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table that contains, amongst other columns, a column of browser versions. And I simply want to know from the record-set, how many of each type of browser there are.

my code is :

```php
$whereBrowser = [['owner', '=', 12]];
        $browser = ProfileTracker::where($whereBrowser)->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])->select([
            DB::raw('browser'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(browser) as value')
        ])->groupBy("browser")->orderBy("value", "desc")->take(10)->get();
```

output :

```
          "browser": [
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome Mobile 84",
                  "value": 144
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome Mobile 80",
                  "value": 84
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome 84",
                  "value": 27
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome 30",
                  "value": 22
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome Mobile 83",
                  "value": 19
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Chrome Mobile 47",
                  "value": 10
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Firefox 79",
                  "value": 8
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Mobile Safari",
                  "value": 8
              },
              {
                  "browser": "Mobile Safari 13.1.2",
                  "value": 6
              }
          ],
         
      }
```

I want to group all browsers, without the browser version like this:

```
            "browser": [
                {
                    "browser": "Chrome",
                    "value": 306
                },
                {
                    "browser": "Safari",
                    "value": 14
                },
                {
                    "browser": "Firefox",
                    "value": 8
                },
            ],
           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can pull this off is to look for browser names in strings and parse them to just the browser name in the query. So something like `Mobile Safari 15.1.2` will be parsed to `Safari`:

```
ProfileTracker::selectRaw('
    CASE 
        WHEN browser LIKE '%firefox%' THEN 'Firefox'
        WHEN browser LIKE '%chrome%' THEN 'Chrome'
        WHEN browser LIKE '%safari%' THEN 'Safari'
    END AS browser_name,
    count(1) AS count
')->groupBy('browser_name')->get();
```

Please note that I have removed parts of the query builder, to make this example a little more readable. You can add back whatever you need yourself.

This will give you:

```
Chrome  1
Firefox 1
Safari  2
```

My test data is:

```
"Chrome Mobile"
"Firefox 79"
"Mobile Safari 13.1.2"
"Mobile Safari 15.1.2"
```

Comment: thank you , but i got this error  [link] https://prnt.sc/tyzjnl

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: my database is PGSQL

Comment: I changed the double quotes with single quotes and it works now

Comment: Perfect. I have updated the answer with your modification.

Answer (score 0):

you can substr browser name by using SUBSTRING_INDEX function to extract first string  :

```
      $browser = ProfileTracker::where($whereBrowser)
      ->selectRaw("browser,SUBSTRING_INDEX(browser, ' ', 1) AS BrowserName,COUNT(browser) as value")
      ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()])
      ->groupBy("BrowserName")->orderBy("value", "desc")->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: first thank you for your, answer I tested this code but it gives me 500 internal server error
 i'm  using laravel and postgresql not mysql

Comment: I think SUBSTRING_INDEX function not exist in Postgresql

Comment: I doubt this would work with the data he has. In case of `Mobile Safari 13.1.2` it would just find `Mobile`, but should find `Safari`. Please check my answer above.